# Python selenium headless mode missing elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I am using selenium to scrape the amazon search results page. As I was wrapping it up, I moved my scraping to headless mode as it will save on efficiency. However **in headless mode, certain page elements do not become available** such as sponsored brand. It works perfectly fine when using non-headless mode, but **fails using headless even after setting the following options:**

```
options = Options()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

PS: I tried with and without the commented section as well as with just the commented section.

For clarification purposes I screenshotted each example: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1rNM.jpg) is what it looks like when it run it in headless mode and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SffLL.jpg) is what it normally looks like (without headless mode as well as normal user browsing). I am wondering **what else needs to be added** in order for the sponsored brand information to show up when I run it on headless mode. I am thinking it may be a problem with JavaScript not communicating properly with the browser?

As always, thank you in advance!!

Comment: The Javascript interpreter is PART of the browser.  There aren't any communications problems.  It's possible (just theorizing here) that headless mode sets a different value for the CSS `media` attribute, and the branding might depend on that.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's a great question. I did some research, there does not seem to be a chrome option that can change (or restore) the CSS media attribute. Any idea on how to (in layman's terms) import the same CSS media attributes that appears in the non-headless browser to the headless browser?

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between the two snapshots

Comment: @DebanjanB My apologies!! I just noticed that mix up. Please refer back to it again and let me know your thoughts. Thanks!!

Comment: @DebanjanB my apologies! I am rather new to contributing to this platform. How would you recommend I go about being in a mode for you to answer if I already found the answer to my problem? I want to be as beneficial to learning as I can.

Comment: @LukeHamilton I know you are new :) keep asking good questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the latest *Google Chrome v95.0*

- When you use the normal **headed** [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser the following [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) is in use:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
  ```
- Where as when you use the [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) browser the following [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) is in use:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
  ```

The presence of the additional *`Headless`* parameter/attribute is intercepted as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot). Hence you see the difference.