# HeadlessChrome is not regarded as a real user by Barnes and Noble website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, access-denied

The reason I'm using Chrome-Headless is because it's acts like a real browser, but when I direct chrome-headless + Selenium to this Barnes and Noble link:

https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-woman-they-could-not-silence-kate-moore/1138489968?ean=9781728242576

I get this response, without navigating to any other page

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>


</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
 
You don't have permission to access "https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-woman-they-could-not-silence-kate-moore/1138489968?ean=9781728242576" on this server.<p>
Reference #


</p></body></html>
```

I understand that I would need to add headers and all, but how is this different than just a regular GET request + Headers?

What else is giving Chrome-headless away to the Barnes and Nobel in particular?

What am I doing wrong?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the following [*Access Denied*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331061/7429447) error page:

[image: Access Denied]

due to presence of the keyword [***Headless***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026154/7429447) within the [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent)

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36
```

---

### Solution

You can override the default *useragent* with some other regular [UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70510724/7429447) as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = Options()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36")
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-woman-they-could-not-silence-kate-moore/1138489968?ean=9781728242576")
  driver.save_screenshot("barnesandnoble.png")
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: barnesandnoble]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to set a custom name for the user-agent using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62502930/7429447)
- [How to change the displayed operating system information within the useragent using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62934224/7429447)
- [How to change the Google Chrome UserAgent using the ChromeDriver installed through webdriver_manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62503645/7429447)