# How to run a script in a headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

There is a script-parser site written in Python with Selenium, if I run it in headless mode, so as not to open the browser window, it can not find the desired item and spar the information from it. If I run it without headless mode, it works fine

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(f'''https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/38862450/detail.aspx?targetUrl=SP''')
time.sleep(20)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(20)

element = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="address-rate-mini")
btn = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="btn-base")
```

It can't find the `btn` I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Browser Detection:

Some webpages can **detect that you are scraping their site by looking at your user agent**. A *normal browsing agent looks like this*:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

However in *headless mode, your browsing agent looks like this*:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

Whatever site you are scraping probably detected the "Headless" tag and possibly restricting the btn element from you.

### Solution:

A simple solution to this would be to add the following **Selenium option to programmatically change your user agent**:

```
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36"')
```

### More Information:

[Python selenium headless mode missing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70024441/python-selenium-headless-mode-missing-elements)

Comment: I added this line before the driver call, but nothing has changed

`options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36"')`

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")`